# Grabbing multiple web pages in php

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing, domdocument, domxpath

I,m using `DOMDocument` and `DomXPath` to grabbing a web page content and parse it. It works very well for single page, but when I use it inside a loop for 50 pages, it becomes unusable.

Is there a better way to do this?

[Update]
Here is my code

```
    $start = microtime(true);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes

    $updaters = Updater::all();

    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    foreach($updaters as $updater) {
        @$doc->loadHTMLFile($updater->link);

        $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
        $nodes = $finder->query($updater->grabber->linkgrab);

        $links = array();
        foreach($nodes as $node) {
            $links[] = $node->nodeValue;
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {

            @$doc->loadHTMLFile($links[$i]);

            $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
            $title = $finder->query('/html/head/title')->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: What becomes unusable? it runs out of memory?

Comment: It works very slowly. e.g. for 50 pages in 10 minutes i have no results. @this.lau_

Comment: Yes that's probably too long, maybe it's stuck in an infinite loop, but without seeing your code it's not possible to help.

Comment: "i have no results"? What do you mean by "no results"? That you do not get a response since you are _guessing_ URLs? If so then you run into timeouts. 50*30 secs is quite some time...

Comment: Post the code so we can see what can be the issue...It could simply mean that the element was not found, but it should be a lot more faster, so, something is wrong with your code.

Comment: I mean it is very slow and I need a method faster than DOMDocument to grab web pages. @arkascha

Comment: No its not an infinite loop. for 1 page it takes about 1 second, for 10 pages it takes about 10 seconds, and for 50 pages i  dont have any result in 10 minutes. I add my code @this.lau_

Comment: PHP is not the fastest language on earth, and parsing a full HTML into a DOM is probably time consuming. I'm not sure it's possible to optimize your use case, if you need speed perhaps use a compiled language like Go.

Comment: Is there a faster method than DOM for this task in **php**? @this.lau_